# Translating publish dates to Arabic

Tags: translation

I need to translate post publish dates from English to Arabic.

I uploaded the po file from this link, using WPML string translation: http://wpcentral.io/internationalization/ar/

The .po file has translations for months, but not years and dates.

I want a date like 22 January 2015 to appear as ٢٢ يناير ٢٠١٥, but I can only get it to show up as 22 يناير 2015

What am I missing out?

Comment: Switch to one of the default themes, turn off all plugins and try again. If the problem stays, please report back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Anyone with a similar problem can add this code to their site plugin or theme functions.php

```
function convert_numbers_to_arabic( $string ) {
    $arabic_numbers = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '٤', '۵', '٦', '۷', '۸', '۹', '.');
    $english_numbers = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.');
    return str_replace($english_numbers, $arabic_numbers, $string);
}

add_filter( 'get_the_time', 'wpse_convert_arabic_time' );
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'wpse_convert_arabic_time' );

function wpse_convert_arabic_time( $the_time ) {
    if ( get_bloginfo( 'language' ) == 'ar' ) { 
        $the_time = convert_numbers_to_arabic( $the_time );
    }
    return $the_time;
}
```